# Unable to retrieve source package from Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I've installed a managed package in my scratch org, and now I want to retrieve the source.

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./mdapipackage -p field_trip -u redacted -w 10
```

I get the error of:

```
ERROR running force:mdapi:retrieve:  The metadata retrieve operation failed: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: No package named 'field_trip' found.
```

Because I don't know the accurate name, I've tried listing the installed packages with

```
sfdx force:package1:version:list
```

With no results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `sfdx force:package:installed:list -u <user_name_goes_here>` , to list the installed packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve is only to retrieve from the package if you are in the org where the managed package is developed .

A managed package source code is generally hidden except the source code thats exposed by the vendor .

If you want to see the managed packages installed you will simply run the below using the username of the scratch org or alias

```
sfdx force:source:pull
```

Comment: `sfdx force:source:pull`, doesn't show a managed package.